# $\phi(x,{}\cdot{})$ independent of $\mathcal{G}\subset \mathcal{F}$. Calculate $\mathbb{E}[\phi(X,\omega)\mid\mathcal{G}]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I am trying to understand a proof in the book "Backward Stochastic Differential Equations" by Jianfeng Zhang, however twice the following Problem is used. I have actually no idea how to prove this problem. Has anyone an idea? Thanks in advance.

Let $\mathcal{G}\subset \mathcal{F}$ be a sub $\sigma$-algebra. Let $X$ be measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{G}$ and $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)\times\mathcal{F}$-measurable. Assume, for each $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$, that $\phi(x,{}\cdot{})$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$. Show that
$$\mathbb{E}[\phi(X,\omega)\mid\mathcal{G}]=\mathbb{E}[\phi(x,{}\cdot{})]\mid_{x=X}.$$

Comment: There is something off about this identity, please check it. I suppose the right-hand side should read $\mathbb{E}[\phi(x,\cdot)] \big|_{x=X}$.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Sorry for missing this.